# Timer in android?

Tags: android

Can some body please help me in this.I am implementing a swiper application that reads the card details and returns a string.I want to implement a timer that will check whether this string is returned or not.Can somebody please tell me how to find whether a string contains a value after the oncreate method is called.I basically want to know how to check a string contains a value upto a certain time(20 seconds).If no value is retirned upto 20 seconds i will be showing a pop up.I am new to android programming any help would be appreciated.
Following is what i am trying to do in my oncreate method.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               if(result.length()==0)
{
Log.e("TAG","No value received");
}
                }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 20000,1000);
```

Comment: what's the problem with your Timer and TimerTask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 void run() {
   // your job to be done in delay seconds
 }, delay);
```

Comment: +1 for suggestion the preferred Android way for this use case.